# JavaScript Comparing random array objects to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, compare

I am doing a mobile application in JavaScript for an assignment using arrays

I get 5 random questions from 1 array and display them as buttons are clicked

```
var showQuestions = new Array(5);
var questions = new Array(8);
var answers = new Array(8);

questions[0] = "What is the first planet";
questions[1] = "What is the second planet";
questions[2] = "What is the third planet";
questions[3] = "What is the fourth planet";
questions[4] = "What is the fifth planet";
questions[5] = "What is the sixth planet";
questions[6] = "What is the seventh planet";
questions[7] = "What is the eighth planet";

answers[0] = "Mercury";
answers[1] = "Venus";
answers[2] = "Earth";
answers[3] = "Mars";
answers[4] = "Jupiter";
answers[5] = "Saturn";
answers[6] = "Uranus";
answers[7] = "Neptune";

function generateQs()
{
    for(var i = 0 ; i < showQuestions.length ; i++)
    {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
        showQuestions[i] = questions[rand]
    }
    window.location = "#page2";
}

function showQ()
{
    clean = "";

    for(var j = 0 ; j < showQuestions.length ; j++)
    {
        document.getElementById('goHere').innerHTML = clean;
        document.getElementById('goHere').innerHTML = showQuestions[0]
    }
}
```

What I need to do is be able to compare questions with answers for a corresponding answer.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, using zero for the array index everytime you don't have that many options, as you only have one question and one answer in your arrays ?

Comment: `var arr = []; arr.push('first'); arr.push('second');`

Comment: It also doesn't appear that you're memoising the option you're adding to showQuestions, so you might end up with multiples of the same question being asked.

Comment: That was an issue I was running into as well but I was just gonna to use multiple pages

Comment: Just realized that they were all saving in index 0, mistake when writing it out. Fixed now